# Is there a media query type way to switch js files based on device?

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

I'm attempting to get my mobile layout working for my site and while the media query with the different stylesheet appears to be working I can't seem to figure out if it's even possible to load a separate javascript file attached to that media query.

Clarification:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="desktop.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
      media="only screen and (max-width: 720px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2.0)" href="jesusmobile.css">
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
```

and at the end of my html doc before the /body

```
<script src="my.js"></script>
```

Basically I want to have it so that when my site uses the "mobile.css" stylesheet I can also tell it to use a different .js file. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17022222/appending-script-src-script-to-head-based-on-screen-width

Comment: thanks! seems to be what i'm looking for, although I'm pretty noob to js so I'm not too sure I can get it to work.. thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this link http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/08/combining_media.html

```
if (screen.width < 600) {
    // don’t download complicated script
    // use low-source images instead of full-source ones
}
```

or

```
if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 900) {
    // scripts
}
```