# Trying to append html string fail with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to append the following string to head with jQuery :

```
"<script type='text/javascript'> window['adrum-app-key'] = 'dummy';</script>"
```

But it always fails. Trying to do the same with 'Hello' string for example works as expected.
Following the code snippet I use to append the string :

```
var integrationScriptTag = handlebars.partials.integration(integrationData);
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('head').append(integrationScriptTag.trim());
    });
```

First string is the result of parsing integrationData.
Any help will really be appreciated.

Edit: I realize I misguided some of you with the first string. It is just a representation of what is produced by the first line of the second code snippet. So it doesn't really matter if it is some quote marks or not. The fact is I don't use a literal but rather a variable which is equal to the first string. I corrected the syntax so that there is no more confusion.
Here is the jsFiddle reproducing the problem.
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8u8qf01e/1/)

Comment: you need to escape the embedded single quotes inside your string.

Comment: I don't know why you mark it as off-topic. The problem is easily reproducible and is not resolved by simple typographical fix. Here is a jsFiddle simulating the problem [link](http://jsfiddle.net/8u8qf01e/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found that you cannot append script tags to head with jQuery this way.
I found some solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413737/how-to-append-script-script-in-javascript) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17022222/appending-script-src-script-to-head-based-on-screen-width) (look at the first code snippet of the selected answer for the second link).

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it:

```
'<script type=\'text/javascript\'> window[\'adrum-app-key\'] = \'dummy\';</script>'
```

or this would too:

```
'<script type="text/javascript"> window["adrum-app-key"] = "dummy";</script>'
```

Essentially you have quotes mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Use this, it will fix the issue

```
'<script type=\'text/javascript\'> window[\'adrum-app-key\'] =\'dummy\';<\/script>'
```

Answer (score -1):

The head is parsed prior to the execution of javascript. So you probably have to perform the `append` outside the `$(document).ready` function.

Comment: The syntax highlighting on SO actually gives the answer in this case.

Comment: That could be a typo while redacting the question.